# Exclude file extension

Tags: php

I recently moved my site to a new host and I now have to include the .php file extension to all php files when navigating them. With my previous host, I was able to get to them either way.

```
http://example.com/myphpfile.php
```

or

```
http://example.com/myphpfile
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this so I don't need the .php extension to navigate to the page?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's apache, you're probably looking at `MultiViews`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it I guess. Having this in .htaccess seems to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to .htaccess

create an .htaccess file in the directory you want to enable this in, and in that file type

```
SetHandler php-script
```

that should force all pages to process as PHP for apache

Comment: for future/similar reference hits on this...  `AddHandler php-script .html` will force PHP to process html files

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. When I added this, it actually downloads the .php file to the users computer.